# Remove Feature from Layer on Zoom - OpenLayers 3.19

Tags: openlayers, layers, features, zoom

I'm trying to erase the content of my layer when I zoom but even if I clear the source, the icons are back on the map again. I'm blocked since one week, please help. There is my code

```
/**** Define the layer and the vector of feature ****/
var vectorSource = new ol.source.Vector({});
var vectorLayer = new ol.layer.Vector({
    source: vectorSource
});

/**** Define the map ****/
var map = new ol.Map({
     controls:[],
     layers:[new ol.layer.Tile({source: new ol.source.OSM()})],
     target: document.getElementById('main-map'),
     view: new ol.View({
         center: [0,0],
         zoom: 3
     })
});

/**** Define one icon ****/
var iconStyle = new ol.style.Style({
    image: new ol.style.Circle({
      radius: 5,
      fill: new ol.style.Fill({color: 'yellow'})
    })
});

var feature = new ol.Feature({
    geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(["0","0"]),
    style: iconStyle
});
vectorSource.addFeature(feature);

/* On change, erase the previous icon (not working) and add a new one */
map.getView().on('change:resolution', function() {
    vectorLayer.getSource.clear();

    var feature = new ol.Feature({
        geometry: new ol.geom.Point(ol.proj.fromLonLat(["1","1"]),
        style: iconStyle
    });
    vectorSource.addFeature(feature);
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getSource` is not property, it is method. It should be called as `getSource()`. See demo: https://jsfiddle.net/xb1v1qsm/

Comment: Thanks. I have found that's was not my probleme but I appreciated some help for debug. Tnhaks a lot.